# Rotate enemy character to see player character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making the enemy character to follow the player character.

In the `FixedUpdate` method the enemy character move toward the player character,
then in the `Update` method character rotates to the player character.

However, with this script, somehow enemy character is just nudging and gets stuck.

Where is the mistake, what's wrong???

```
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject tObj;
    private Vector3 latestPos; 
    public string targetObjectName;
    public float speed = (float)1.0;
    void Start()
    {
        tObj = GameObject.Find("player");
        latestPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 diff = transform.position - latestPos;  
        latestPos = transform.position;

        if (diff.magnitude > 0.01f)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(diff); 
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate(){
     
        
        Vector3 dir = (tObj.transform.position - this.transform.position).normalized;
        float vx = dir.x * speed;
        float vz = dir.z * speed;
        this.transform.Translate((float)(vx / 50.0),0,(float)(vz / 50.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` **not** in `unityscript` which is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like language used in previous Unity versions and is long deprecated by now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Package Manager "Standard Assets", Inside Unity put two FPSController one should be Player and the second can be Enemy.

I know this does not answers your question but its a faster way to ad Enemy.

[AI Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioX4x.png)

Just remove the camera, Audio Source and First Person Controller Script as in image.

The Code for AI:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowAI : MonoBehaviour
{

    public  CharacterController _controller;
    public Transform target;
    public GameObject Player; 

    [SerializeField]
    float _moveSpeed = 2.0f;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
  

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()  {

        Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;

        direction = direction.normalized;

        Vector3 velocity = direction * _moveSpeed;

        _controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        Vector3 lookVector = Player.transform.position - transform.position;
        lookVector.y = transform.position.y;
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookVector);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rot, 1);


    }
}
```